# Preserve order of keys when merging two objects in Javascript lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have two objects x and y

```
var x = { 1: 1, 2: 2, hi: "hi" };
var y = { hello: "hello", coffee: "coffee" };
```

I want to merge them into one.

```
_.extend(y, x);
```

I am expecting all the keys in y to come first followed by keys in x. However, this is what I am getting in the result

```
{1: 1, 2: 2, hello: "hello", coffee: "coffee", hi: "hi"}
```

The numeric keys are appearing first, followed by keys in y and x.

How do we get all keys in y to be first followed by keys in x?

Comment: Object don't have something such as order of keys. Only arrays do!

Comment: keys are not ordered in objects, they're not supposed to be. If you want a particular order in which to pull information out you have to define that order.

Comment: I don't want the keys to be ordered. I just want to preserve the existing order when extending the two objects.

Comment: The problem here is that there is no *"existing order."* What use case do you have that makes this feature necessary? If you explain that, we might be able to recommend the appropriate language construct.

Comment: I am displaying the extended object in a dropdown using the keys. I want the keys in y to appear first followed by a separator and keys in x.

Comment: Then don't merge the object just work with them separately! And after you merge them how would you still able to tell where one ends and where the other begins?

Comment: can you convert all values to object which have two properties as priority and value ? Then sort the objects based on the value of priority

Comment: My component can use only one object, so I have to merge them into one. I have a line separator key appended at the end of y to separate y and x. This is working fine until I got numeric keys when the order got changed

Comment: var x = {1: { p: 1, value: 1}, 2: {p: 3, value: 2}, 3: {p:2, value: 3}}...Something on these lines?

Comment: *"I am displaying the extended object in a dropdown."* Could you post the relevant code for us to see? That would certainly help.

Comment: @gyre I am jsending the object to my dummy component in React. It just displays whatever keys are present in the object in the same order.

Comment: I see we have a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, there is no order to an object. Though most browsers do respect the order, so if you're talking something non-critical, you *might* be able to get away with trusting browser behavviour (even though it isn't spec - spec being no order).

A more spec-friendly approach would be to use an array, something like:

```
var x = { 1: 1, 2: 2, hi: "hi" };
var y = { hello: "hello", coffee: "coffee" };

var a = [];

_.mapValues(x, function(v, k) {
  a.push({ key: k, value: v });
});
_.mapValues(y, function(v, k) {
  a.push({ key: k, value: v });
})

// ES6 (no lodash):
var a = [
    ...x.map((value, key) => ({ key, value })),
    ...y.map((value, key) => ({ key, value })),
];
```

http://codepen.io/cjke/pen/BWjPOO?editors=0010

If for some odd reason, you can't change your dropdown, you can do it the object way (but see disclaimer at the start):

```
var x = { 1: 1, 2: 2, hi: "hi" };
var y = { hello: "hello", coffee: "coffee" };

var a = {};

_.mapValues(x, function(v, k) {
  a[k] = v;
});
_.mapValues(y, function(v, k) {
  a[k] = v;
})
```

http://codepen.io/cjke/pen/BWjPqO?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure if lodash was a requirement for this solution but I read that you are using this code in react so JSX works there too.  I noticed that the key names are the same as the values.  So I thought that we could remove one or the other.  I chose to substitute the inherited key for a numeric key which would be generated by the function.  The concat creates the order, and the forEach that assigns a numeric key maintains that order. There are probably more eloquent solutions out there but I hope this helps out!

```
var x = { 1: 1, 2: 2, hi: "hi" };
var y = { hello: "hello", coffee: "coffee" };

function createObj(obj1, obj2) {
  let result = {};
  const arr = [...Object.values(obj2).concat(Object.values(obj1))];
  arr.forEach((v, i) => {
    result[i] = v;
  })
  return result
}

createObj(x, y)
```